# suncalc package in R: incorrect dates/timezone issue?

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to add dawn/dusk/night/day variables to animal tracking data. However when I try to use getSunlightTimes function from the suncalc package it calculates for the wrong date. Everything is set to tz = UTC, although my sys.timezone is Pacific/Auckland.

For example if the input date is 2021-02-05 it gives me the sunrise time 2021-02-04 17:42:24 and sunset time 2021-02-05 07:28:19. Location is near New Zealand (lon = 174.9776, lat =
-36.20939) so the time of day makes sense, but just seems to be offset by one day?

Example dataframe:

```
datetime <- c("2021-02-05 11:00:00", "2021-02-05 13:00:00", "2021-02-05 15:00:00")
lat <- c("-36.20939", "-36.20952", "-36.20979")
lon <- c("174.9776", "174.9772", "174.9764")
date <- c("2021-02-05", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05")

df <-cbind.data.frame(datetime, lat, lon, date)
```

This is my current code:

```
#Using the SunCalc package get times for sunrise, sunset, night, and nightENd
df$datetime <- strptime(df$datetime, format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime)
df$date <- as.Date(df$datetime, tz = "UTC")

sun_all <- getSunlightTimes(data = df, 
                            tz = "UTC",
                            keep = c("sunrise", "sunset", "night", "nightEnd"))

#Append to main data frame
df$sunrise <- sun_all$sunrise
df$sunset<- sun_all$sunset
df$night <- sun_all$night
df$nightEnd<- sun_all$nightEnd

#Create new column labelling each data point as the Time of Day (ToD)
df$period <- rep(" ", length.out = nrow(df))

# Assign labels based on time ranges
df$period[df$datetime > df$sunrise & df$datetime < df$sunset] <- "day"
df$period[df$datetime > df$sunset & df$datetime < df$night] <- "dusk"
df$period[df$datetime > df$nightEnd & df$datetime < df$sunrise] <- "dawn"
df$period[df$period == " "] <- "night"
```

Comment: Hi Squid! Welcome! It appears in your code you are actually using the argument `tz = "UTC"`, where you probably want to use `tz = 'NZST'` or something similar

Comment: @Mark My data is collected in UTC :)

Comment: in that case maybe you need to change the time zone :-) `lubridate::with_tz(example_datetime, tzone = "Pacific/Auckland")`

Comment: @Mark Suncalc has issues with NZ time zone (https://github.com/datastorm-open/suncalc/issues/8). As all my data is in UTC and I have set suncalc to work in UTC so I am confused where the issue is - do I need to set my system timezone to UTC too?

Comment: hmmm it might be helpful if you can show me what your desired output would be!

Comment: I just want the correct date to be passed on: if the input date is 2021-02-05 I want the sunrise time from that day rather than 2021-02-04 17:42:24 which is the day before

Comment: There's a few different options: 1. you can wait for the developers of suncalc to fix it (unlikely, as the bug was first reported 3 years ago, and the developers still haven't responded, 2. you fork the package and fix it yourself (a lot of work), or 3. you just add 1 to all of the dates after suncalc has done it's thing